# JPA ManyToMany links wrong entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Let's say we have 4 entities: Movie, studio, site and tag. Movie, studio and site can have 0 or many tags (a tag has 0 to many to each). A movie has 0 or 1 site (a site has 0 to many movies). A movie has 0 or many studios (a studio has 0 to many movies). I have implemented these relations by introducing TagCollection and StudioCollection as below. TagCollection has  oneToOne mapping with Movie, and a manyToMany with Tag (Same for StudioCollection). I did it this way because:

- I want all the tag/studio to go to the same table, regardless of the entity they are attached to
- The link table would have a unique id back to the owning entity, which mean that when I query the relationship, I never have to specify if the tag should be for a movie or a site or a studio: the id is unique and exists only for 1 entity.

This plan failed, as when I save a movie with some tags, and retrieve it, the tags are linked to a studio or any other entity but its original owner. The test is as below (followed by the code). Any idea what I am doing wrong ? I suspect the ids in my link tables are wrong, but I cannot prove it nor see why this happens (it is not due to a typo or a bad affectation). The full code is published [here](https://github.com/SandrewCheru/SpringLearning) in case more is needed but below is part of my implementation and the failing test. Thx for your time.

```
@Test
    public void addedMoviesWithAttributesArePersisted() {
    final MovieBuilder mb = new MovieBuilder();
    mb.title("Title");

    // Add a site to the movie
    final Site site = new Site("Site TEst");
    mb.site(site);

    //Add 2 studios to the movie
    final Studio studio1 = new Studio("Studio 1");
    final Studio studio2 = new Studio("Studio 2");
    final StudioCollection studioCollection = new StudioCollection();
    studioCollection.add(Sets.newSet(studio1, studio2));
    mb.studioCollections(studioCollection);

    // Add 2 tags to the movie
    final Tag tag1 = new Tag("Tag 1");
    final Tag tag2 = new Tag("Tag 2");
    final TagCollection tagCollection = new TagCollection();
    tagCollection.add(Sets.newSet(tag1, tag2));
    mb.tagCollection(tagCollection);

    final Movie movie = mb.build();
    this.underTest.persist(movie);

    final Set<Movie> foundMovies = this.underTest.findByTitle("Title");
    assertFalse(foundMovies.isEmpty());
    assertEquals(1, foundMovies.size());
    assertTrue(foundMovies.contains(movie));
    final Movie foundMovie = foundMovies.iterator().next();

    // This fails
    assertFalse(foundMovie.getTagCollection().isEmpty());

    // Querying for all entities gives this results
    this.underTest.getAll();
    // TagCollection: id=[1] Values=[[]]
    // TagCollection: id=[2] Values=[[Tag [id=1, tagName=Tag 1], Tag [id=2, tagName=Tag 2]]]
    // TagCollection: id=[3] Values=[[]]
    // TagCollection: id=[4] Values=[[]]
    // Site: id=[1] + Name=Site TEst] + tag=[TagCollection: id=[1] Values=[[]]]
    // Studio id=[1] + Name=Studio 2] + tag=[TagCollection: id=[1] Values=[[]]]
    // Studio id=[2] + Name=Studio 1] + tag=[TagCollection: id=[2] Values=[[Tag [id=1, tagName=Tag 1], Tag [id=2, tagName=Tag 2]]]]
    // Movie: id=[1] + Title=Title] + tag=[TagCollection: id=[1] Values=[[]]]
    }
```

Here is how I have it now:
Tag Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TAG")
public final class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String tagName;

    // Getter & Setter and constructors
}
```

Tag Collection:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TAG_COLLECTION")
public class TagCollection {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "tag_link", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tagCollection_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private final Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    // Getter & Setter and constructors
}
```

Site:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SITE")
public class Site implements MovieEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private final TagCollection tags = new TagCollection();

    // Getter & Setter and constructors
}
```

Studio:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDIO")
public class Studio implements MovieEntity, Representable, Taggable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private final TagCollection tags = new TagCollection();

    // Getter & Setter and constructors
}
```

Studio Collection:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDIO_COLLECTION")
public class StudioCollection {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "studio_link", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "studioCollection_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "studio_id"))
    private final Set<Studio> studios = new HashSet<>();

    // Getter & Setter and constructors
}
```

Movie:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOVIE")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private final TagCollection tagCollection = new TagCollection();

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private final StudioCollection studioCollection = new StudioCollection();

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "site_id")
    private Site site;

    // Getter & Setter and constructors
}
```

Comment: This is probably too complex for a SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like what you are describing:

[image]

But it didn't seem like your Entities matched your conceptual model. You might model the above ER Diagram like so:

```
@Entity
public class Tag {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
    @ManyToMany private Set<Movie> movieTags;
    @ManyToMany private Set<Studio> studioTags;
    @ManyToMany private Set<Site> siteTags;

@Entity
public class Movie {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private int id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="movieTags") private Set<Tag> tags;
    @ManyToOne private Studio studio;
    @ManyToOne private Site site;

@Entity
public class Site {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private int id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="siteTags") private Set<Tag> tags;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="site") private Set<Movie> movies;

@Entity
public class Studio {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private int id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="studioTags") private Set<Tag> tags;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="studio") private Set<Movie> movies;
```

and use it like so:

```
tx.begin();
Tag tag = new Tag();
Movie movie = new Movie();
Studio studio = new Studio();
Site site = new Site();

tag.setMovies(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(movie)));
tag.setStudios(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(studio)));
tag.setSites(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(site)));

site.setMovies(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(movie)));
studio.setMovies(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(movie)));
em.persist(movie);
em.persist(site);
em.persist(studio);
em.persist(tag);
tx.commit();
em.clear();

List<Tag> r = em.createQuery("select distinct t from Tag t left join fetch t.movieTags left join fetch t.studioTags left join fetch t.siteTags", Tag.class).getResultList();
System.out.println(r.get(0) 
        + Arrays.toString(r.get(0).getMovies().toArray())
        +":"+Arrays.toString(r.get(0).getStudios().toArray())
        +":"+Arrays.toString(r.get(0).getSites().toArray()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and your answer. It helped me to achieve what I wanted